# RecyclerView not appearing in my Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

SO I have a recycler View in a Fragment but it won't display  the data for some reason: and I can't seem to find the reason of why it doesn't display the cards inside the recycle view. So any insight on this would be helpful i attach my code so you guys can take a look and give me some feedback, 
Cheers!!

this is my fragment: where I make the recycle view.
    package lucas.app_2001;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
    static ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    private  RecyclerView.LayoutManager rv;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    ImageButton rate;


    public OneFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_activity, container, false);
        final FragmentActivity c = getActivity();
        RecyclerView  recyclev = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.Recycle);
        rv = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        Person.initializeData();
        adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
        recyclev.setLayoutManager(rv);
        recyclev.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclev.setAdapter(adapter);
        rate = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        initializeData(c);

        return view;
    }
    public static void initializeData(){
        persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma, R.drawable.icorating0, "75pts."));
        persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma, R.drawable.icorating0, "20pts."));
        persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.emma, R.drawable.icorating0, "30pts."));
        persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.emma, R.drawable.icorating0, "40pts."));
    }


}
```

This is the card view java class:

```
package lucas.app_2001;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.Override;

import lucas.app_2001.R;

public class CardViewActivity extends Activity {

    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    ImageView personPhoto;
    ImageButton rate;
    TextView Points;
    LinearLayout Card;
    CardView  cardview_activity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        findViewById(R.id.rate);
        setContentView(R.layout.cardview_activity);
        personName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        Card = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Card);
        personAge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        rate.setImageResource(R.drawable.icorating0);
        Points = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Points);
        Card.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iphone_wallpaper_01b1);
        cardview_activity.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.iphone_wallpaper_01b1);

        personName.setText("Emma Wilson");
        personAge.setText("23 years old");
        personPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.emma);
        Points.setText("75pts.");
        rate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.rate);



    }
}
```

This is my recycle view adapter:1

```
package lucas.app_2001;

import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView personName;
        TextView personAge;
        ImageView personPhoto;
        ImageButton StarRate;
        TextView Points;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
            StarRate = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
            Points = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Points);
        }
    }

   private List<Person> persons;

    public RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){

        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);

        return pvh;
    }
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {

    personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
    personViewHolder.StarRate.setImageResource(persons.get(i).rate);
    personViewHolder.Points. setText(persons.get(i).Points);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return persons.size();
}
}
```

the persons class where the data from the recycle view is held:

```
package lucas.app_2001;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {
    String name;
    String age;
    int photoId;
    int rate;
    String Points;
    static List<Person> persons;


    Person(String name, String age, int photoId, int rate, String Points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.photoId = photoId;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.Points = Points;
    }

    public static void initializeData(){
        persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma, R.drawable.icorating0, "75pts."));
        persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma, R.drawable.icorating0, "20pts."));
        persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.emma, R.drawable.icorating0, "30pts."));
        persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.emma, R.drawable.icorating0, "40pts."));


    }
}
```

Im not really sure where my mistake might be nor where to look so What I'm looking for here is some guidance on where I might have messed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your onCreateView:
where does

```
 Person.initializeData();
```

"Person" come from?
Why is initializeData() even static?

Shouldn't it be

```
OneFragment.initializeData()?
```

Comment: added the person class, which is where the info is held

Comment: Appreciate someone talking look at the entire code just to make sure somebody gets some well-needed help.